# Validate input for month

Tags: javascript, string, validation, input

I want to allow only formats of this kind: **19.30 Friday 2/10**. Well 19:30 instead of 19.30 would also be acceptable. How to do that easily? Note that an answer with completely new code would also be accepted.

---

Here is my attempt, but it fails in the month part. `str` is the string we try to validate.

```
var ok = true, index = - 1;
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  if(i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 4) {
    if(!$.isNumeric(str[i])) {
      ok = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(i == 2) {
    if(str[i] != '.' && str[i] != ':') {
      ok = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(i == 5) {
    if(str[i] != ' ') {
      ok = false;
      break;
    } else {
      ++whitespaces;
    }
  }
  if(i > 5 && index == -1) {
    if(!isLetter(str[i])) {
      if(str[i] == ' ') {
        ++whitespaces;
        index = i;
      } else {
        ok = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
for(var i = index + 1; i < str.length; ++i) {
  if(i == index + 1 || i == index + 2 || i == index + 4) {
    if(!$.isNumeric(str[i])) {
      ok = false;
      break;
    }
  } else {
      if(str[i] != '.' && str[i] != '/') {
      ok = false;
      break;
  }
 }
}

if(!ok || whitespaces != 2) {
   alertify.error("Bad format, match creation failed!");
   return;
}
```

Comment: is this a string input field?

Comment: I get the string with a `prompt` @vittore.

Comment: Why don't you use a regex ? It will be a bit complicated, but not that much !

Comment: @QBernard because I do not know how to! But I would like! Can you post an answer with an example on that? But please, make me learn, not just copy the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regex solution, you just need to test if your string matches this regex:

**Regex:**

```
[0-9]{2}[\.:][0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{4,7} ([0-2][0-9]|[3][01])\/(0[1-9]|1[12])
```

**Example:**

This is a working Snippet:

```js
var str = "19.30 Friday 2/10";
var regex= /[0-9]{2}[\.:][0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{4,7} [0-9]\/[0-9]{2}/
if (str.match(regex)) {
  alert("String matched .");
} else {
  alert("String unmatched !!");
}
```

This is exactly what you need.

**Explanation:**

```
[0-9]{2}[\.:][0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{4,7} [0-9]\/[0-9]{2}
```

- `[0-9]{2}` matches two digits.
- `[\.:]` matches `.` or `:` as yopu stated.
- `[0-9]{2}` is to match the second part (two digits) after `.` or `:`.
- `[A-Z][a-z]{4,7}` matches the day name :  it begins with an Uppercase and then we expect from `4` to `7` characters as `Friday` is the shortest one and `Wednesday` is the longest one.
- `[0-9]\/[0-9]{2}` matches the last part of `2/10` .

Comment: Seems to work, but why? :) You see I could just cp the code and that's it. However, I haven't study regex. Can you please help me learn?

Comment: @gsamaras Okay, you are right about it. I edited my post with the right explanation of then whole Regex, the regex can be optimised but just keen in mind that whenever you need to validate a string the easiest way to do it is to use Regular Expression.

Comment: The explanation is very good! However, I have some questions. `[A-Z][a-z]{4,7}`, will expect the first letter to be an uppercase. Then we expect 4 to 7 characters of lowercases. However Friday has 5 uppercases. Does the indexing start from zero? But we count the amount here, aren't we? Then, about `[0-9]\/[0-9]{2}`, we need to allow day/month format, thus we should have `[0-31]\/[1-12]`? Or I am missing something? Of course you deserve a +1 for the nice explanation!

Comment: Yes you are right for Friday it should be `{5-7}` and for the month and day yes we need `([0-2][0-9]|[3][01])\/(0[1-9]|1[12])` and this is [a live Example test](https://regex101.com/r/lN4dY9/1) you will find all the explanation there, I am Editing my post.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt it is convinient for users to use such an input field, even if you have a mask on the field, having said that I see several approaches:

- use regex to validate input field ( easiest)
- use any of the input box mask plugins (google - there are hundreds of them)
- (one i prefer) use normal controls for date and time ( ie html5 date etc , or jquery.ui date and time input) and format javascript Date object to desired date/time format.

Also, don't use prompt to get data from users, use one of gazillion of javascript modals (jquery.ui, bootstrap, etc each have one)

Example regex: `(\d\d?):(\d\d?)\s(\w+)\s(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)`

Formatting javascript Date object to your format (using moment.js for simplicity):

```
moment(myDate).format('hh:mm Do dd/MM')
```

Also take a look at plugins for date / time input, like this [one](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

**UPDATE:** To clarify my point - I really doubt that the whole reason for your requirement is just to get date in such format, you are going to use date for something, that is why you better of start having date as a date, not some string formatted to match legacy requirement. Given that you better use UI controls that facilitate input of Date , ie html5 date input, or any of the plugins that doing the same. That will give you ability to work with the date after and if needed format it to your desired format ( as in example with moment.js for advanced formatting)

Comment: I had searched the internet for something ready. However, I found dates of this fashion: `time 15/05/2015`. I want the day to be *visible*, that's why I went back to primitive solutions.

Comment: I will need to study on regex (since I can only assume what your example means) and the Date object then...

Answer (score 1):

A quick example

```
var re = /^[0-2][0-9](\.|:)[0-5][0-9] ([a-z]*) [0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$/;
// the regex above checks 
// if the first number is a valid hour (between 00 and 24), then . or :,
// a valid minute number between 00 and 59,
// if you have a space, then a string, another space,
// then a valid month (0 - 12)

// How to use ?
var text = "19.30 Friday 2/10";
console.log(re.test(text)) // return true
```

Comment: Thanks (u deserve a +1), but I still need some guidance. What does `*` do?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should work for you:

**If 2/10 stands for February 10**

```
/^([0-9]|1\d|2[0-3])[\.:]([0-9]|[1-5]\d)\s(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s([0-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/
```

**If 2/10 stands for October 2**

```
/^([0-9]|1\d|2[0-3])[\.:]([0-9]|[1-5]\d)\s(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s([0-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/([0-9]|1[0-2])$/
```

### RegEx Explanation:

- Regex in JavaScript is between `//`
- `^...$` says, from start to end, match the pattern given inside
- What is inside `()` is a group and `([0-9]|1\d|2[0-3])` matches `0` - `23`. Expression says match (`0-9` `OR` `starting with 1 and \d(any digit)` `OR` `a two digit number where 10th digit should be 2 and unit place should be between 0-3 inclusive`)
- `[\.:]` - Next token could be a `.` or `:`, `.` needs an escape because it is a meta character in regex and matches anything.
- `([0-9]|[1-5]\d)` - you will know what this is, referring to first point.
- `\s` matches a single white space
- `(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)` matches any of the given pattern inside
- `([0-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` for date and month.

> Open for comments

```js
var input = ["19.30 Friday 2/10",
             "19.60 Friday 2/10",
             "1.32 Friday 2/10",
             "10.30 Sunday 2/10",
             "22.30 Monday 2/10",
             "19:30 Saturday 12/10",
             "19.30 Friday 14/10",
             "19.30 Friday 2/21",
             "19:1 March 10/10"         
            ];

var output = "";
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output += (input[i] + " " + /^([0-9]|1\d|2[0-3])[\.:]([0-9]|[1-5]\d)\s(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s([0-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/([0-9]|1[0-2])$/.test(input[i]) + "<br/>")
}

document.write(output);
```

Comment: `19.30 Friday 2/21 true` should be wrong. In Europe, we have the second operand to serve as a month. So it should allow numbers up to 12, not 21. However, you did not explain at all how the regex works and I have no idea about regex'es, thus I can't edit. However, you deserve a +1 for showing the testcases.